# How do I make the player move once and then stop for a bit when it reaches a 'Tile'

Tags: python

```
class TileModel:
pixel = 64
gap = 5
x1 = 400
x2 = x1 + pixel + gap
x3 = x2 + pixel + gap
x4 = x3 + pixel + gap
x5 = x4 + pixel + gap
x6 = x5 + pixel + gap
x7 = x6 + pixel + gap
x8 = x7 + pixel + gap
x9 = x8 + pixel + gap
x10 = x9 + pixel + gap
y1 = 100
y2 = y1 + pixel + gap
y3 = y2 + pixel + gap
y4 = y3 + pixel + gap
y5 = y4 + pixel + gap
y6 = y5 + pixel + gap
y7 = y6 + pixel + gap
y8 = y7 + pixel + gap
y9 = y8 + pixel + gap
y10 = y9 + pixel + gap
xCoords = (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)
yCoords = (y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10)
```

..........................................................

```
def game():
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        global running
        running = False
    for i in TileModel.xCoords:
        if player.x == i:
          ` player.xChange = 0
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
             player.xChange += -10
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
            player.yChange += -10
        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
            player.xChange += 10
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            player.yChange += 10
```

*Im making something like a board game. I want to make it move like in chess where it doesnt move  constantly. I defined the x and y coordinate of the tiles and put them in a xCoords and yCoords tuple. I already have something like if the player reaches a tile's x coordinate, it stops. The problem is that it doesnt move after that because the if condition is always True. How do I negate the speed only once when it reaches a tile?*[this is the game I screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODpXr.png)

Comment: you will need to indent your code probably especially for python.

Comment: already did that i was thinking if there was something like executing a line of code ONCE if condition is fulfilled. in this case, if a player reaches a tile, the if statement would occur constantly so you cant move